# Actualizar colummnas con un cursor en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Hola amigos quiero actualizar el campo monto de cada fila , con una operacion aritmetica pero me toma el primer valor.

este es mi codigo :

```
declare  @day1 int,@day2 int


declare cUpdateMonto cursor global

for


select DiasSolicitados,DiasAProbados from INCAPACIDAD
where DiasSolicitados<>DiasAProbados and year(FechaInicialSolicitada)=2020 


for update 

open cUpdateMonto


fetch  cUpdateMonto into @day1,@day2




while (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)

begin


update INCAPACIDAD
set Monto=(@day1-@day2)*31.00
where DiasSolicitados<>DiasAProbados and year(FechaInicialSolicitada)=2020  



fetch  cUpdateMonto

into @day1,@day2


end

close cUpdateMonto

deallocate cUpdateMonto
```

me sale asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

El error está aquí:

```
update INCAPACIDAD
       set Monto=(@day1-@day2)*31.00
       where DiasSolicitados<>DiasAProbados and year(FechaInicialSolicitada)=2020
```

Es que no estás actualizando una sola fila (la actual del cursor) sino todas las filas del lote siempre con el mismo valor de `@day1` y `@day2`, calculo que el valor que queda es el último.

La solución, pasa por leer además el `id` de fila que desconozco cual es:

```
select IdFila, 
       DiasSolicitados,
       DiasAProbados 
       from INCAPACIDAD
       where DiasSolicitados <> DiasAProbados 
             and year(FechaInicialSolicitada)=2020
```

Y luego

```
fetch cUpdateMonto into @Id, @day1, @day2
```

Y por último:

```
 update INCAPACIDAD
           set Monto=(@day1-@day2)*31.00
           where IdFila = @Id
```

Por otro lado, puedes resolver todo con una consulta de actualización y evitar el costo asociado al uso de cursores:

```
update INCAPACIDAD
       set Monto=(DiasSolicitados - DiasAProbados)*31.00
       where DiasSolicitados<>DiasAProbados 
             and year(FechaInicialSolicitada) = 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

creo que no es necesario un cursor para esa operación, aparte de que consume mucho recuerso, hay mejores maneras mas rapida de hacerlo.

Aqui una manera de que se realize saludos.

Declare una variable de tipo tabla para simular tu tabla.

```
--Declaración de tabla aux solo para demostrar datos con lo que muestras
DECLARE @T TABLE(
DiasSolicitados INT,
DiasAprobados INT,
Monto DECIMAL(18,2)
)

--Insercción de valores
INSERT INTO @T (DiasSolicitados,DiasAprobados)
VALUES(60,20),(30,28),(31,14),(15,10),(45,19),(25,16),(30,16),(140,136),(19,17),(30,0),(30,16)

--DECLARAMOS UN CTE PARA OBTENER LOS DATOS QUE SE ACTUALIZARAN
;WITH CTE_Update AS (
SELECT * FROM @T
--WHERE
--Aqui pones tu where que aplicas
)
--Aplicamos el update
UPDATE CTE_Update
SET Monto=(DiasSolicitados-DiasAprobados)*31.00

--Verificamos los datos
SELECT * FROM @T
```

Obteniendo como resultado esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias !